# What is the meaning of below Smartcard Command?

Tags: smartcard, apdu, scosta

00E00000 1A 62 18 820138 8302 3F00 8A0101 8C 08 7F FF FF FF FF FF FF 21  8D 02 3F02

I am aware until 3F00 which is file identifier for Master File but I don't know meaning of further command. I refer ISO 7816-4 but still cant trace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *Create File* command, belonging to ISO 7816-9 (Commands for Card Managment). Creation of of the MF is explicitly mentioned as out of scope  there (concerning administrative commands the urge to be compliant to a standard is noticably weaker anyways), so you should turn to the [SCOSTA specification](http://www.scosta.gov.in/scosta_1.pdf) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much I refer Scosta Specification, Now I understand until Security Attribute format i.e 8C 08 0F Can you please advise on further bytes?

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje: There is only one data object left specifying the file ID of the file containing the security environments (SE), see chapters 4.3 and 6.2.6 of SCOSTA. If you are asking for the 7 trailing FF bytes within data object 8C - no idea, this does not comply to anything standardized I know of.

Comment: Yeah actually those FF bytes causing confusion